# context free grammar issue

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

I need help with my context-free grammar for this language:

```
{b^4 n^m bd^n n^3n+m | m,n >= 0}
```

So far I got this:

```
S-> bbbbXbY
X-> n | E
Y-> dYnnnX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming S is start symbol, E is empty word (), your language is `{b^4 n^r b d^s n^(3s+r) | r,s ≥ 0}`.

## The correct grammar

```
S → bbbbN
N → bD | nNn
D → dDnnn |
```

## Explanation

- `S` generates `b^4` on the left and switches to `N`. It never occurs in the derivation again.
- `N` generates `n^r` on both sides, then `b` in the middle and switches to `D`. After that it never occurs in the derivation again.
- Finally `D` generates `d^s n^(3s)` and finishes the derivation.

```
S                               (start symbol)
→ b^4 N                         (applied S → bbbbN)
→ b^4 n^r N n^r                 (applied N → nNn r-times)
→ b^4 n^r bD n^r                (applied N → bD)
→ b^4 n^r b d^s D (nnn)^s n^r   (applied D → dDnnn s-times)
→ b^4 n^r b d^s (nnn)^s n^r     (applied D → )
```

## Mistakes in the original grammar

Your grammar generates empty language, because `Y` will always be present in the product of each derivation step (infinite recursion). There is also a fundamental problem with context: the first sequence of `n`s is generated by `X` from `S → bbbbXbY` independently of the second one generated by `X`s from `Y → dYnnnX`. If you add `Y →` , the language will be `{b^4 n^r b d^s n^(3s+t)}`. And the grammar will be ambiguous, as `bbbbXbddYnnnXnnnX` can be generated (using `Y → dYnnnX` twice) and the final sequence of `n`s can be usually generated in many ways.

## Steps to fix the original grammar

- Add `Y →`  to stop infinite recursion.
- Move `X` from the end of `Y → dYnnnX` to the end of `S → bbbbXbY` to get rid of ambiguity.
- Chain the `X`s in newly created `S → bbbbXbYX` together to force the context. The same amount of `n`s must be generated by both of them.

Now you have the correct grammar at the top of this answer.

Comment: @JustAUser You are welcome. :-) But please avoid posting “thank you” comments as it is not what comments are meant for. See Pay it forward section of [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) in help and [Thanking users who answered my question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17878/238706) and [Is it acceptable to write a thank you in a comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126180/238706) on meta.  Accepting my answer and/or upvoting it is enough.